# Error in "Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Antiforgery.AbpAutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, swagger, aspnetboilerplate

I am new to Asp.net Boilerplate and I follow along on the tutorials made by Lee Richardson in YT. I have also read the documentation in asp.net boilerplate page about web and dynamic API.

Now, I am stuck with this error when I tried to use Swagger and Postman in POST,PUT and Delete request

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Antiforgery.AbpAutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult: Information: Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 400
```

but no errors I get in Get Method. Have I missed something in configuration or any files?. Please help. I appreciate the help and thank you in advance.

Here is my DTO and Service class

```
[AutoMap(typeof(SinkingGroup))]
    public class SinkingGroupDto : EntityDto<int>, IFullAudited, ISoftDelete
    {
        [Required]
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public int MembersCount { get; set; }
        public long? CreatorUserId { get ; set ; }
        public DateTime CreationTime { get ; set ; }
        public long? LastModifierUserId { get ; set ; }
        public DateTime? LastModificationTime { get ; set ; }
        public long? DeleterUserId { get ; set ; }
        public DateTime? DeletionTime { get ; set ; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get ; set ; }
    }
```

```
[AbpAuthorize]
    public class SinkingGroupAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<SinkingGroup, SinkingGroupDto> 
    {
        public SinkingGroupAppService(IRepository<SinkingGroup,int> repository)
            : base(repository)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error. Have you tried (i) clearing browser cache and (ii) browser incognito mode?

Comment: Yes, I tried clearing browser cache and used incognito both google chrome and IE edge

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help @aaron. I figured out the reason why I get this errors.
It is because I was running the web.mvc project instead of web.host project. If using web.host, this will redirect to swagger ui upon starting the project and click authorize to login using swagger.

Now, I am able to run it without seeing those errors again and able to insert data to table.

Comment: Posting the stack trace would have helped to identify that quickly.